# How do the atomic orbitals look like in reality?

Tags: orbitals

We all know about atomic orbitals and their 3D structure. But the structure in theoretical. What does these orbital really looks like

Comment: Well, what does a mathematical function look like in your idea?

Comment: I wanated to know how does the electrons spin in an atom. I mean what does it look like when the electrons spin... The theoretical models shows how they spin... But i wanna know how do they looks like when they spin

Comment: This theoretical model is the best we got. Sure, it would be nice to look at the real orbital with your own eyes, but you can't do that anyway.

Comment: The electrons don't spin around the nucleus. They just exist somewhere in the general vicinity of it and the probability of finding one at any particular point is quite well described by the quantum mechanical description.

Comment: You cannot "see" an electron to determine whether it is spinning or not. The "spinning" of the electron is not measurable; it makes no sense to speak of it in science. However, you can measure an electron's angular momentum; it makes sense to speak of angular momentum in science. Therefore, don't think of the electron as a "spinning" object (which we can never know or observe); think of it as simply having "intrinsic" angular momentum.

Comment: It's not just theoretical. That's like saying the shapes of protons and atoms is theoretical. We have seen them with scanning tunneling electron microscopy! Are you saying electrons are theoretical also? What these orbitals really look like is a hybrid of the basis orbitals (not a theory) that follow VSEPR guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

Atomic orbitals are just the solution of Schrodinger's wave equation. They help us to understand better the behaviour of electrons. Electrons behave more like waves and atomic orbitals can be thought of as places where the probability of finding those electrons is maximum. In reality, there is no such place as an atomic orbital.

Comment: The question is not what equation is associated with the eigenvalue that describes orbitals. It does not ask about probability as you are assuming the question asked about exact shapes. And in reality there are such places as atomic orbitals, if not matter could collide and pass through itself.